# Do pets count towards "per attack" and "on hit"?

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm playing a witch doctor with a spec that does very few actual direct attacks (i.e, me running in and hitting or casting a spell.) However, I've got pets that are always attacking or the Pirahna pool that are attacking as well.

If I have a weapon that says `10% chance on hit` to apply something, do my pet hits and the Pirahna "tick" count towards that 10% chance on hit? What about something that says `x% of thorns applied on every attack`?

Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 3):

Pets have a [proc coefficient of 0](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Proc_Coefficient), meaning they can not trigger "on hit" effects.

Answer (score 1):

In general, no.

However, pets can sometimes proc related legendary abilities.  In [patch 2.5](https://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/20529333/patch-250-ptr-notes-3-10-2017), Blizzard added the ability for Wizard pets to proc the [Manald Heal](https://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/manald-heal) ability.  This is the only exception I'm aware of.